# Php and mysql foreign key data insertion

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in mysql database(product table and product category table)
The product category table  has category id as primary key and has a column category name.The product table has product id as primary key and category id as foreign key.From my form I want to insert the category id in my product table. I am using php to post form data.How should I do this?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You shouldn't need to do more than just pass a valid category id as the category id in your insert. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I literally don't know how to insert the foreign key values.

Comment: You insert it just like you would for any other value. The only difference is that it will fail if you pass in an id that doesn't exist in the product category table.